# Create grandchildren associations in the same Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get something like this in one class using ActiveRecord:

```
grandfather = Person.create(name: "Grandfather")
son = Person.create(name: "Son", parent: grandfather)
grandson = Person.create(name: "Grandson", parent: son)

grandfather.children.map(&:name)
=> ["Son"]

grandfather.grandchildren.map(&:name)
=> ["Grandson"]
```

I wrote the children association this way:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Person", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Person", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

And it works, but I got stuck with grandchildren. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this:

Models

```
Person
Child
Grandchild
```

A `Person` `has_many :children`
A `Child` `belongs_to :person`
A `Child` `has_many :grandchildren`
A `Grandchild` `belongs_to :child`

Till now we haven't established the relationship between `Person` and `Grandchild`, so we basically need to use `Child` relationship to establish this relationship with `has_many :through` associations, So:

A `Person` `has_many :grandchildren, through: :children`
A `Grandchild` `belongs_to: person, through: :children`

I have not tested this code
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried to defined by association `has_many :grandchildren, through: :children`, but failed. Rails complains `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

But you can defined as a method,

```
def grandchildren
    Person.where(parent: children)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and this works for me to find grand children of a Human.

```
class Human < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, :foreign_key => "parent_id" , :class_name => "Human"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Human", optional: true
  has_many :grand_children,  class_name: :Human, through: :children, source: :children
end
```

But I couldn't find way to reverse the association to find grand parent of a human.
I tried:

```
  belongs_to :grand_parent, class_name: :Human, optional: true
```

but got nil class.

I fix it by following

```
class Human < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, :foreign_key => "parent_id" , :class_name => "Human"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Human", optional: true
  has_many :grand_children,  class_name: :Human, through: :children, source: :children
  has_one :grand_parent, class_name: :Human, through: :parent, source: :parent
end
```